DASK Future stuck on 'pending' when running a function (python)
I am trying to run a function in parallel using DASK. I am able to run the entire code (.py) file in my terminal (miniforge) on my local PC.
I need to be able to run it on a HPC, however the computation of results using DASK hangs in a pending state when trying to execute the code on the HPC (no issues when run locally).
The relevant code is below:
res_paths = os.listdir(Paths.HPC_settings["res_folder"])
subs_cols = time_steps["date_from"].values[1:]
for SUBS_name in res_paths:
    subs_ID = SUBS_name[10:]
    SUBS_file = os.path.join(Paths.HPC_settings["res_folder"], SUBS_name)

    _task = delayed(Functions.subs_df)(SUBS_file, subs_cols) #The function is called
    tasks[_task.key] = SUBS_name #Task ID
    lazy_results.append(_task) #Append tasks

results = client.compute(lazy_results) #Compute the tasks
progress(results)

# Collecting dask results
task_results = {}
res_dict = {}
for r in as_completed(results):
    print(results) # results have been printed
    if r.status not in res_dict.keys():
        res_dict[r.status] = []
    res_dict[r.status].append(r)
    
    if r.status == "finished":
        task_results[tasks[r.key]] = r.result()

The process hangs in the section which goes through the as_completed(results).
I have printed the 'results' in the loop to check what they look like and majority are hanging in a 'Pending' state raster than 'Finished'. The results finish without issues when running locally on my PC.
[<Future: pending, key: wrapper-934e7b13-f314-41f4-b90c-b2c1611ac7f5>, <Future: pending, key: wrapper-b0da016d-e91c-4bc2-bf37-482da4818088>, <Future: pending, key: wrapper-fd806791-1856-46d2-83c1-1d56d8ea5e58>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, key: wrapper-52279b69-d5f4-4e2c-b9e1-564d7de41c3f>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, key: wrapper-367927dc-8fdd-41c9-ab5b-d6fe59f41c07>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, key: wrapper-5ae3077e-8f86-48da-98a4-9f23900f3573>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, key: wrapper-8e1d4bf5-9baa-492e-a5f9-0e1b548b39cc>, <Future: pending, key: wrapper-16e8034c-aa34-4653-9e95-c103ab414738>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, key: wrapper-17788dfa-c48c-4b50-830b-93dbb6e66c39>]

Any ideas?

What Scheduler or Cluster type do you use to interact with Dask on your HPC system? Pending state could mean that there are no workers to run the tasks. Do you have any log outputs?
